# Which design pattern would be best for this case?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a class, called PolicyProvider, at present with the following (abridged) interface:

```
public interface IPolicyProvider
{
    List<Policy> GetRenewalPolicies(Client client, int financialYear);
}
```

The purpose is quite obvious - every year, the insurance renews for the client, and they will get a number of new policies.

The thing is, the policies change year by year.  Therefore, a concrete implementation of the class needs to be changed every year (or amended with lots of ugly little "if's" evaluating the financial year).  I can see that over time this will become horrendous.

In this case, what design pattern is most appropriate?

Comment: I don't really think you should ask for "design pattern". You should ask for OO design and use design pattern only if it emerges from this design or if you are 100% sure this is good fit for that pattern.

Comment: Most likely a factory pattern, with your core `PolicyFactory` creating policies for any given client. I recommend starting with a `PolicyFactoryFactory` class, a factory of factories, that is, capable of creating a `PolicyFactory` for particular year (be it `PolicyFactory2012` or `PolicyFactory2013` etc.). :)

Comment: You can try to decompose the code into a number of "code blocks", and then see if next year's policy can be composed from these blocks. However, if next year's policy turns out to be unforeseeable (requiring completely new code blocks and behavior), code change is inevitable.

Comment: I would use some kind of config file... editing code every year is a PITA. Adding a line in a txt file or whatever is easy as pie. Or you could store data in a db and let clients put the data in it through an interface.

Comment: +1 @Florian. You probably shouldn't have to change your code to change the policies.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input - most valuable.  Konrad, Im looking into your solution at the moment it sounds like my PolicyProvider class was really a Factory after all.  Perhaps if you put an answer down the bottom I can tick it.

Comment: Florian, I would definitely prefer a solution with no code change.  However it's a little more complicated than my snippet suggests.  A simple implementation of the method might just return a bunch of policies of different types.  Year by year, that might just mean defining what types apply to which year.  But also, their construction changes - so one year PolicyTypeA applies to the Client, but the next it needs to apply to one of their assets... Other changes might occur which are entirely unexpected. Therefore at this stage it seems creating a new factory each year is the way to go.

Comment: @nulliusinverba all right, I added my input as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `nulliusinverba`'s suggestion, I'm creating an answer out of my original comment.

I see it as a scenario for a factory pattern, with your core `PolicyFactory` (or provider) creating policies for any given client.

You could then in turn have a `PolicyFactoryFactory` class, a factory of factories, that is (nevermind the awkward naming), capable of creating a `PolicyFactory` for particular year (be it `PolicyFactory2012` or `PolicyFactory2013` etc.).

Obviously, this metafactory could still be able to parse external files and build policies out of their contents (as Florian suggested).

Answer (score 2):

A standard approach to avoiding "if"s is to use subtyping and dynamic binding. All you need to do is to create subtype policies for each financial year.

Comment: +1.  I would add with a factory whose sole purpose is to instantiate the appropriate policy for that particular year.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Domain Model Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236415.aspx) because "policies" (especially as you've described them) are subject to frequent change and you need to keep them sufficiently isolated so that you will not confuse or disrupt the "normal" path of execution.

> **Reasons to Use the Domain Model**
>
> In those cases where the behavior of the business is subject to a lot of change, having a domain model will decrease the total cost of those changes. Having all the behavior of the business that is likely to change encapsulated in a single part of our software decreases the amount of time we need to perform a change because it will all be performed in one place. By isolating that code as much as possible, we decrease the likelihood of changes in other places causing it to break, thus decreasing the time it takes to stabilize the system.